# Finding bases for R(T) and N(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: M_{3 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \to M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by:

$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} \end{bmatrix}\right)$ (3 rows) $= \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} + a_{12} &  a_{21} + a_{22} \\ a_{31} + a_{32} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (2 rows)

Find bases for $R(T)$ and $N(T)$, verify dimension theorem.

I am wondering what is the formal way to solve this? I just looked at it and thought that 3 2x2 matrices, one with a 1 in position (1,1), one with a 1 in position (1,2), and one with a 1 in position (2,1) and all zeroes elsewhere is a basis for R(T). Is there a more rigorous way to do it?

For N(T) I just thought since all positions must have a value of 0 that if in position (1,1) we have $a_{11} + a_{12}$, we should have $a_{11 }= -a_{12}$ and the same for the other 3 positions.

Is this correct?

Comment: I see no $R$ or $N$ is the statement, so you might begin explaining what $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ are. I think you probably are referring to kernel and image subspaces (of $M_{3\times 2}(\Bbb R)$ respectively of $M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$) but I cannot make the correspondence of kernel, image with those letters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ belong to $N(T)$ and are linearly independent, and $T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right)$, $T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right)$ and $T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right)$ belong to $R(T)$ and are linearly independent, we have,

As above matrices form a base $M_{3 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, we have the first three are based on $N(T)$ and the three base $R(T)$.